# Overmounting a file in unix/aix

Tags: unix, filesystems, aix, mount, unmount

can someone help to answer these?..not able to find anywhere on google.

- What is the meaning of overmounting a file in Unix/aix?
- what is the  command to overmount a file
- what happens if the file is overmounted?

Comment: I do not believe the term _overmounting_ is standard. Do you have some more context in which we can place these questions?

Comment: i came across this term overmounting in https://wiki.roggeware.nl/index.php/AIX:AHAFS_ahamoddir.c

Comment: 1. Become hidden by a mount command, affecting its directory. 2. mount 3. It will be unreachable till umount.